# How can I change the maximum message size from client side in SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

In my application I send emails using SMTP. I send the email message as an html email.

If the html content is small then I can send the emails correctly using SMTP but when the email message has lengthy html contents the mail does not end up in the account.

What is the reason for that?

Is there any command or code to change the message size passing to smtp server from the client side?

Below is the SMTP code I am using to send emails:

```
function smtp_mail($from, $to, $subject, $message, $headers="", $params=array()) {
    $errno = "";
    $errstr = "";
    $smtpConnect = fsockopen("mail2.allramhosting.com", "25", $errno, $errstr, 20);


    if (!empty($smtpConnect)) {

        if ($params['use_html']) {
            $extra_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
        }
        $headers = "To: " . $to . "\nFrom: " . $from . "\nSubject: " . $subject . "\nDate: " . date('r') . "\n" . $extra_headers . $headers;

        if (substr($headers, -1) == "\n") $headers = substr($headers, 0, -1); // Our last character should not be newline


        fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO networkssms.com\r\n");
        fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: " . $from . " SIZE=1000000\r\n");
        fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: " . $to . "\r\n");
        fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA\r\n");
        fputs($smtpConnect, $headers . "\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($smtpConnect, $message . "\r\n.\r\n"); // send message and finish
        fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
        fclose($smtpConnect);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the calling function:

```
<?php
$subject = "UnTouched Ticket Notification";
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$from = "test@domain.com";
$part = "<html><body>\n";
$part .= "<div style='background-color: #EEEEEE;;padding: 10px 10px 20px;width: 650px; float:left;font-size:18px;'>\n";
$part1 = "<div style='width:500px;'>\n";

$part1 .= "<div style='width:450px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 30px 0 20px; height:auto; float:left;font-size:15px;margin-left:50px;'>\n";
$part3 = "</div></div></div>\n";
$part3 .= "</body></html>\n";

$center_part1 = 'Dear Admin ,';
$center_part = "You have opened 25 tickets . But the following tickets are not updated yet ,\n";
$center_part2="<div style='width:345px;color:#000000;font-size:12px;margin-left:25px; font-weight:bold; height:auto; margin-top:30px;'>\n";

$new = '<table height="92" style="border:2px solid #DCDCDC; width:565px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr style="background-color:#E5E5E5;">
    <th height="35">Ticket #</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Untouched Days</th>
    <th>Untouched Hours</th>
    <th>Last Updated Date</th>
  </tr>';
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
$new.= "<tr>
    <td align = 'center' height='30'>".$i."</td>
    <td align = 'center'>test</td>
    <td align = 'center'>terst</td>
    <td align = 'center'>".$i." Days</td>
    <td align = 'center'>".$i." Hours</td>
    <td align = 'center'>".$i."</td>
  </tr>";
}
$center_part2.=$new."</table></div>\n";
$message = $part.$center_part1.$part1.$center_part.$center_part2.$part3;
        if($to){
            smtp_mail($from, $to ,$subject, $message,"MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n");
        }

?>
```

Can you identify what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for that?

The server is configured that way.

> If there is any command or code to change the message size passing to smtp server from client's side?

No.

Comment: So you mean that i never send mail with larger html content using this code?

Comment: Then how can i send such mail using smtp?

Comment: If there is any situation like that coming what i do?Because the mail contents change to smaller is not possible.

Comment: Put the contents on a web server and just put a link in the message. Do you really need for the contents to be that large, though? Typical server limits are in the megabytes range. If you have embedded images, can you make them external?